# Minimal Sufficient Statistic for $f(x) = e^{-(x-\theta)}, \; \theta < x < \infty, \; x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, sufficient-statistics

My question comes from Exercise 6.9(b) of *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger:

> 6.9: Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ 
> (b) $f(x|\theta) = e^{-(x-\theta)}, \quad \theta < x < \infty, \quad -\infty < \theta < \infty$.

This exercise appears to be a straighforward application of the following theorem:

> **Theorem 6.2.13.** Let $f(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$ be the pmf or pdf of a sample $\mathbf{X}$. Suppose there exists a function $T(\mathbf{x})$ such that, for every two sample points $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, the ratio $f(\mathbf{x}|\theta)/f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)$ is constant as a function of $\theta$ if and only if $T(\mathbf{x}) = T(\mathbf{y})$. Then $T(\mathbf{X})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

A little algebra shows that
$$\frac{f(\mathbf{x}|\theta)}{f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)} = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - x_i) \right) \frac{I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{x}_{(1)})}{ I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{y}_{(1)})}$$

for all $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} \in (\theta,\infty)^n$. Now it's clear that the desired implication "$f(\mathbf{x}|\theta)/f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)$ is constant as a function of $\theta$ if and only if $T(\mathbf{x}) = T(\mathbf{y})$" depends solely upon the above ratio of indicator functions. If $\mathbf{x}_{(1)} = \mathbf{y}_{(1)}$, then $\frac{I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{x}_{(1)})}{ I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{y}_{(1)})} = 1$ for all $\theta \in (-\infty, \mathbf{y}_{(1)})$ (and undefined on $[\mathbf{y_{(1)}},\infty)$), so the ratio is constant in $\theta$ for all $\theta$ where it is defined. And if $\mathbf{x}_{(1)} < \mathbf{y}_{(1)}$, then
\begin{align*}
    \frac{I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{x}_{(1)})}{ I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{y}_{(1)})} &=
    \begin{cases}
     1 & \text{ if } \theta \in (-\infty,\mathbf{x}_{(1)}) \\[2pt]
     0 & \text{ if } \theta \in [\mathbf{x}_{(1)},\mathbf{y}_{(1)})
    \end{cases}
   \end{align*}
(and is undefined for $\theta \geq \mathbf{y}_{(1)}$), so in this case the ratio clearly depends on $\theta$.  But if $\mathbf{y}_{(1)} < \mathbf{x}_{(1)}$, then $\frac{I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{x}_{(1)})}{ I_{(\theta,\infty)}(\mathbf{y}_{(1)})} = 1$ for all $\theta < \mathbf{y}_{(1)}$  (and undefined everywhere else). If the ratio is constant as a function of $\theta$ if and only if $\mathbf{x}_{(1)} = \mathbf{y}_{(1)}$, then we can straightforwardly conclude that $T(\mathbf{X}_{(1)})$ is a minimal sufficient statistic. But in the case where $\mathbf{y}_{(1)} < \mathbf{x}_{(1)}$, is the ratio of indicator functions considered to be constant as a function of $\theta$? Why or why not? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Edit 2/23/22: As @Henry mentioned in the comments, the situation is clarified if we change the part of the theorem that says

> the ratio $f(\mathbf{x}|\theta)/f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)$ is constant as a function of $\theta$

to the new statement

> there exists some $k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) > 0$ (a strictly positive function which does not depend on $\theta$) such that $f(\mathbf{x}∣\theta)=k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})f(\mathbf{y}∣\theta)$ for all $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ in the sample space and all $\theta \in \Theta$.

I would just like some "official" confirmation of this in the form of a theorem in a textbook. Any relevant references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On the right track. Delayed exponential dist'n where $\theta$ is the delay. Minimum is sufficient, but because it always at least a bit above $\theta.,$ it is biased. So, the next step using it in practice is to see if you can multiply it by a constant (depending on sample size) to make it unbiased. Maybe google the relevant Wikipedia page.

Comment: The answer to your second question is essentially no.  You have the slightly difficult case that your definition suggests division by $0$:  to avoid it here you want the similar statement there is a strictly positive value $k$ such that $f(\mathbf{x}\mid \theta) = k f(\mathbf{y}\mid \theta)$ for all $\theta$. That is not the case here when $y_{(1)} < x_{(1)}$ or $y_{(1)} > x_{(1)}$ and $\theta$ is in the gap between them, since you would then need $0$ to be strictly positive

Comment: @Henry: Thanks for your comment! I guess the theorem given by Casella and Berger implicitly assumes that $f(\mathbf{x}|\theta) > 0$ for all $\mathbf{x}$. In your restatement, I take it that $k$ is allowed to be a (strictly positive) function of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, but not $\theta$? Also, do you have a reference containing this version of the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your edit, the amended statement of the theorem in Casella and Berger makes your theorem slightly more general. This particular statement can be found in Theorem 2.3(iii) in *Mathematical Statistics* by Shao.
The statement is given below:

**Theorem 2.3(iii) (Shao)** Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a family of distributions on $\mathbb{R}^k$. Suppose that $\mathcal{P}$ contains p.d.f.s $f_P$ with respect to a $\sigma$-finite measure and that there exists a sufficient statistic $T(X)$ such that, for any possible values $x$ and $y$ of $X$, $f_P(x) = f_P(y)\phi(x,y)$ for all $P$ implies $T(x)=T(y)$, where $\phi$ is a measurable function. Then $T(X)$ is minimal sufficient for $P\in\mathcal{P}$.

---

Shao, Jun. *[Mathematical statistics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97553)*. Springer Science & Business Media, 2003.

Comment: Many thanks for the reference!